# Wrong data passed in linked list

Tags: c

Lets say I enter the following:

```
maximum weight number of containers the ship can carry: 10
maximum weight:5
filename: containerlist.txt
```

Output:

```
Weight: 1.82 Shipping Price:2537.76  <---- total exceed 5
Weight: 2.98 Shipping Price:5526.86
Weight: 6.22 Shipping Price:8444.84
Weight: 6.77 Shipping Price:4698.15

Total weight: 5.96 <----- Wrong
```

I tried to put a print my weight below

```
totalweight = totalweight + cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current));
```

to see what value im getting and it turns out to be something else 2.98 and 2.98.

```
typedef struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct{
    char *id;
    double weight;
    double shippingPrice;
}Container;

typedef struct{
    Node *head;      
    Node *tail; 
    Node *iterator;  
    int size;       
} List;

/* Main */

int main()
{
    int maxCnr;
    int file = 0;
    double maxWeight;
    char filename[50]; 
    char choice;
    FILE *input;
    List *list = lst_new();

    printf("********************** WELCOME TO SHIPMANAGER **********************\n\n");
    printf("Please enter the maximum number of containers the ship can carry: ");
    scanf("%i", &maxCnr);

    printf("\nPlease enter the maximum weight the ship can carry: ");
    scanf("%lf", &maxWeight);

    do {
        printf("\nEnter the filename (.txt): ");
        scanf("%s", &filename);

        input = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (input == NULL)
        {
            file = 0;
            printf("File does not exist. \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("File located.\n");
            file = 1;
        }
    }while(file == 0);

    readContainer(list,filename);
    mxCnr(&list, maxCnr);
    mxWeight(&list, maxWeight); 
    printContainers(list);
}
/* ensure that the container does not exceed the maximum number */

void mxCnr(List **list, int mCnr)
{
   Container *tmpContainer;
   List *max = lst_new();
   int i = 0;

   for (tmpContainer = lst_first(*list); i<mCnr; tmpContainer = lst_next(*list))
   {
        Node *previous = NULL;
        Node *current = max->head;

        if (max->size == 0)
            lst_add(max, tmpContainer);     
        else
        {               
            Node *newNode = node_new(tmpContainer, NULL);
            current = max->head;
            while (node_getNext(current) != NULL)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = node_getNext(current);
            }

           if (previous == NULL)
           {
              node_setNext(newNode, max->head);
              max->head = newNode;    
           }
           else
           {
              max->tail->next = newNode;
              max->tail = newNode;
           }
           max->size++;
        }
        i++;
    }    
    lst_delete(*list); 
    *list = max;    
}

/* function to calculate the total weight and to ensure that the weight does not exceed the maximum weight */

void mxWeight(List **list, double mWeight)
{
    Container *tmpContainer;
    List *maxW = lst_new();
    double totalweight= 0;
    printf("maxweight :%lf ", mWeight);

   for (tmpContainer = lst_first(*list); totalweight<=mWeight; tmpContainer = lst_next(*list))
    {
        Node *current = maxW->head;
        Node *previous = NULL;


        if (maxW->size == 0)
        {
            lst_add(maxW, tmpContainer);

        }
        else
        {               
            Node *newNode = node_new(tmpContainer, NULL);
            current = maxW->head;        
            while (node_getNext(current) != NULL && totalweight <= mWeight)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = node_getNext(current);    
                totalweight = totalweight + cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current));    
                printf("%lf ", cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current)));              
            }

            if (previous == NULL)
            {
                node_setNext(newNode, maxW->head);
                maxW->head = newNode;                                           
            }
            else
            {
                maxW->tail->next = newNode;
                maxW->tail = newNode;
            }
            maxW->size++;
        }

    }
    printf("Total weight: %lf", totalweight);
    lst_delete(*list);
    *list = maxW;
}
```

Comment: It would be much better (for us) if you could isolate the problem.

Comment: You should include some example input, results, and expected results.

Comment: Try running your program within valgrind. If valgrind prints out an error message which you don't understand, add the error message to the question.

Comment: Could you please include the source-code for `lst_new()`.

Comment: @JacobPollack, And better for the OP as well. Making an SSCCE often causes you to discover the error.

Comment: Im new to this website. How to i post the codes in the comment?

Comment: @Paul Evans
`List *lst_new(void)
{
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->iterator = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

    return list;
}`

Comment: @Jacob Pollack
My problem is with my mxWeight function. My program reads a .txt file. The combine datas of the weight should not exceed the maximum weight which will be enterd by the user. However, my programs calculate the weight wrongly and it will exceed the limit. I've found that the data that i pass to the mxWeight function in not correct but i dont know where should i correct.

Comment: You should verify cnr_getWeight() is working properly.

Comment: `Im new so sorry for anything. I dont really know how the formatting for the comment box works so i'll just do this.` It would have been polite to spend time reading the FAQ to find out, rather than just apologising then posting anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to exceed total weight, then you need to check before you execced total weight.  (Simpler...)

```
 while (node_getNext(current) != NULL && totalweight<= mWeight)
        {
            Node *old_previous = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = node_getNext(current);    
            totalweight = totalweight + cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current));    
            printf("%lf ", cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current)));
            if (totalweight > mWeight){
               totalweight -= cnr_getWeight(node_getData(current));
               current = previous;
               previous = old_previous;
               break;
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be adding the weight of the first element in the list.  You should check and add that before going into the while.

Comment: Tried something similar.  What is cnr_getWeight()?

Comment: double cnr_getWeight(Container * contain)
{
 return contain->weight;
}

Comment: instead of what i did. is there any other way that i can loop through the linked list? something simpler? By the way, it still will crash

Comment: If you are crashing then something is NULL (or not set) that isn't supposed to be.  Print the pointer out as you loop to see where you have a problem.  Just print it as an int.

Comment: @Jim Pointers are not ints and printing them as ints is undefined behavior, where there is already enough of. To print a pointer, we use `printf ("%p\n", (void *)p);` ever since C89.

Comment: Yes that would be NULL.

Comment: previous = NULL; and you set your old_previous = NULL;

Comment: You are crashing (probably) because you are trying to access a null pointer.  You need to identify that pointer.  Put the print in the while loop (or wherever you think it is crashing) to see where you are having a problem.